# Какой цикл применить в парсинге?

Tags: c#, xpath

Есть страница с новостями ,которую я парсю. Все работает нормально, но только какой мне цикл применить, чтобы спарсились все новости с этой страницы?

```
for ( int add = 1; add < 20; add += 2 ) {
    string title = String.Concat( "//body/div[1]/main/div[1]/table/tr/td[3]/div/table[2]/tr[" + add + "]/td/table/tr/td[2]/a" );
    HtmlNode node = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode( title );
    MessageBox.Show( node.InnerText );
}
```

В `for` нужно выставлять условие и оно не подходит, потому-что я не знаю конечное количество новостей.
Спасибо!

Comment: Попробуйте воспользоваться SelectNodes вместо SelectSingleNode, и получить коллекцию всех узлов.

Comment: Я написал в условие true и вроде получил все новости. Но в конце выскакивает "Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта.".Ну это понятно,что условие перестает быть true. Если воспользуюсь SelectNodes, то что это поменяет? Мне же надо регулярно менять путь к тексту.

Comment: А вот сделайте так, чтобы не надо было вручную менять путь. Составьте такой селектор, который бы выбрал **все** узлы, а не **один**. Получите коллекцию, её можно обойти как обычно.

Comment: Подсказка: ваш код должен выглядеть так: `var nodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes(xpath); foreach (var node in nodes) { MessageBox.Show(node.InnerText); }`.

Comment: Так xpath у меня меняется. Какой мне путь то тогда указывать?

Comment: `//body/div[1]/main/div[1]/table/tr/td[3]/div/table[2]/tr[1]/td/table/tr/td[2]/a`
`//body/div[1]/main/div[1]/table/tr/td[3]/div/table[2]/tr[3]/td/table/tr/td[2]/a`

Comment: Попробуйте сделать одно xpath-выражение, которое покрывает все эти варианты

Comment: Позвольте нам [продолжить обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23184/discussion-between-shatoidil-and-vladd).

Comment: `String.Concat( "//body/div[1]/main/div[1]/table/tr/td[3]/div/table[2]/tr[" + add + "]/td/table/tr/td[2]/a" )` - вот это да - прям супер concat.

Comment: @Qwertiy А че не так то?

Comment: Сложили строки плюсиком, а потом вызвали функцию конкатенации для единстваенной строки :)

Comment: @Qwertiy Спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
HtmlNode node;
for (int add=1; (node = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode(String.Concat("//body/div[1]/main/div[1]/table/tr/td[3]/div/table[2]/tr[", add, "]/td/table/tr/td[2]/a"))) != null; add+=2)
  MessageBox.Show(node.InnerText);
```

Answer (score -1):

Решил проблему таким способом.-

```
for (int add = 1; true; add += 2)
                    { 
                        string title = String.Concat("//body/div[1]/main/div[1]/table/tr/td[3]/div/table[2]/tr[" + add + "]/td/table/tr/td[2]/a");     
                        HtmlNode node = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode(title);
                        if (node == null)
                            break;
                        MessageBox.Show(node.InnerText);
                    }
```

Скажите, такой код имеет право на жизнь или это полная фигня?

Comment: `true` можно убрать.

Comment: @VladD в комменте дал Вам правильный, рабочий код.